# IBM Bluemix Services

Tags: service, ibm-cloud

I have one question according Bluemix Services. Please Help me out if you could help me.
- I want to use third party service that is Cognitive Graph for my project. But i couldn't access it. 
Could you guide me how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Please ask questions about Bluemix offerings at [IBM developerWorks Answers](https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html). Stack Overflow is for programming how-to questions.

The Bluemix Cognitive Graph service is currently in closed beta and therefore not available to the general public. To learn more, you can submit your email address as explained on the service's [Bluemix Catalog page](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/services/cognitive-graph/?taxonomyNavigation=applications).